# Does maven need Internet connection?

Tags: maven

I try to build a project by maven.I tried

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.thoughtworks.app -DartifactId=mvntest -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
```

It worked.And then I tried

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.thoughtworks.app -DartifactId=mvntest
```

I mean,I delete archetypeArtifactId parameter.It fail,I didn't supply it with Internet.the error message is here.Is this parameter made it need Internet?Forget about other depedency.

```
    [INFO] artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart: checking for updates from central    
    [WARNING] repository metadata for: 'artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart' could not be retrieved from repository: central due to an error: Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org   
    [INFO] Repository 'central' will be blacklisted   
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    [ERROR] BUILD FAILURE  
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    [INFO] The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:RELEASE)
```

Comment: Yes, maven needs internet connection to download dependencies/plugins that are not already in your local repository.

Comment: Thank you.@NilsH I know that.But depend on my situation,i think quickstart it's already in my local.so what it need?However I would notice the command next time.

Comment: Based on the error message it is obviously not in your local repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have all the dependencies downloaded on your local repository, then you can run mvn command with -o (offline) option and it should work, unless you don't need any other dependency from the remote repository (when the internet connection is needed).

If you have a repository with all the dependencies needed in your network you can reach on without the outside internet connection, just edit your settings.xml for your intranet dependencies.